# Consultation between dates and groups

Tags: php, mysql

Good morning, I'm doing query across data and within the query need to create a rule to only fetch the values ​​that were selected.

my MySQL

```
$query_rs = "(SELECT * FROM `financ_receita` WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30') UNION ALL (SELECT * FROM `financ_despesa` WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30')";
```

See a picture of how it all starts:

[image]

When I click GENERATE, sends the form to POST and goes like this:

```
HIERARQUIA = 3,4
```

The above two numbers are sent by the field `hierarquia[]` and capture it like this:

```
$hierarquia = implode(",", $_POST['hierarquia']);
```

Is it only possible to make an appointment with the value captured by the variable `$hierarquia`?

Comment: I guess that is all up to how you create your code..

Comment: try SELECT DAYNAME('2007-02-03');

Comment: @putvande I did not ... :)

Comment: If I foce do with just a value hierarchy, would be `AND hierarquia = '3'`, but are more of a value, so it can not do.

Comment: maybe you mean you want something like this `AND hierarqia in ('3', '4', 'etc')` ?

Comment: Discover that it is possible to use the `IN in MySQL`, but I can not anyway. `(
    SELECT planoDeConta FROM ``financ_receita`` 
      WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30' 
      planoDeConta IN (3,4)

) UNION ALL (
  
    SELECT planoDeConta FROM ``financ_despesa`` 
      WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30'  
      planoDeConta IN (3,4)

)`

Comment: IN http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/233af/12

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot `AND` in your fiddles:

```
(
SELECT planoDeConta FROM `financ_receita` 
  WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30' 
  and planoDeConta IN (3,4)
) UNION ALL (

SELECT planoDeConta FROM `financ_despesa` 
  WHERE data BETWEEN '2011-01-01' AND '2013-12-30'  
  and planoDeConta IN (3,4)
)
```

It will return the following

```
PLANODECONTA
3
3
4
4
4
```

Of course if you need some other columns you can add them in your `select` clauses.